# Xpathpattern for Rcrawler package

Tags: r

I have used Rcrawler to extract links for speech, as specified below:

```
speech_links = Rcrawler::LinkExtractor("https://www.federalreserve.gov/newsevents/speeches.htm", urlregexfilter = "https://www.federalreserve.gov/newsevents/speech/")
```

taking one of the links (year) and getting speech links for all the same in that year

```
speech_links_2020 = Rcrawler::LinkExtractor(speech_links$InternalLinks[1])
```

this gives all the links for that year
Now what I am stuck at is how to retrieve speech title, speaker, time and other attributes

I know the code to be used for title is:

```
Rcrawler::ContentScraper(speech_links_2020$InternalLinks[2], XpathPatterns = "//head/title")
```

However, for other attributes, speaker, time and content I am not sure how to specify the XpathPatterns as I am not familiar with HTML.

Can someone please let me know the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following function to get a data frame with columns for date, title, speaker and venue all scraped from the page with the appropriate xpath terms. All you need to do is feed it the year you want.

Note I have used the rvest package, since the Rcrawler package didn't seem to return correct results with these same xpaths:

```r
library(rvest)
library(tibble)

get_fed_speeches <- function(year = substr(date(), 21, 25))
{
  scrape <- function(x, page) html_text(html_nodes(read_html(page), xpath = x))

  page   <- paste0("https://www.federalreserve.gov/newsevents/speech/", 
                   year, 
                   "-speeches.htm")

  xpaths <- list(date    = "//time",
                 title   = "//div[@class = 'row eventlist']//em",
                 speaker = "//p[@class = 'news__speaker']",
                 venue   = "//p[@class = 'news__speaker']/following-sibling::p")

  as_tibble(lapply(xpaths, scrape, page))
}
```

Note it defaults to the current year, so to get speeches for 2020, just do:

```r
get_fed_speeches()
# A tibble: 4 x 4
#   date    title                         speaker           venue                       
#   <chr>   <chr>                         <chr>             <chr>                       
# 1 1/17/2~ Spontaneity and Order: Trans~ Vice Chair for S~ At the American Bar Associa~
# 2 1/16/2~ The Outlook for Housing       Governor Michell~ At the 2020 Economic Foreca~
# 3 1/9/20~ U.S. Economic Outlook and Mo~ Vice Chair Richa~ At the C. Peter McColough S~
# 4 1/8/20~ Strengthening the Community ~ Governor Lael Br~ At the Urban Institute, Was~
```

or for 2015 do:

```r
get_fed_speeches(2015)
#> # A tibble: 54 x 4
#>    date    title                        speaker        venue                          
#>    <chr>   <chr>                        <chr>          <chr>                          
#>  1 12/3/2~ Financial Stability and Sha~ Vice Chairman~ "At the \"Financial Stability:~
#>  2 12/2/2~ The Economic Outlook and Mo~ Chair Janet L~ At the Economic Club of Washin~
#>  3 12/2/2~ Opening Remarks              Governor Dani~ At the Economic Growth and Reg~
#>  4 12/1/2~ Normalizing Monetary Policy~ Governor Lael~ At the Stanford Institute for ~
#>  5 11/20/~ Opening Remarks              Governor Jero~ At the 2015 Roundtable on Trea~
#>  6 11/19/~ Emerging Asia in Transition  Vice Chairman~ "At the \"Policy Challenges in~
#>  7 11/17/~ Thinking Critically about N~ Governor Dani~ At the Brookings Institution, ~
#>  8 11/17/~ Central Clearing in an Inte~ Governor Jero~ At the Clearing House Annual C~
#>  9 11/12/~ The Transmission of Exchang~ Vice Chairman~ "At the \"Monetary Policy Impl~
#> 10 11/12/~ Welcoming Remarks            Chair Janet L~ "At the \"Monetary Policy Impl~
#> # ... with 44 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to parse the json with the speeches

https://www.federalreserve.gov/json/ne-speeches.json

Speakers IDs are here:
https://www.federalreserve.gov/json/nespeakers.json

```
library(httr)
library(tidyverse)

json <- GET("https://www.federalreserve.gov/json/ne-speeches.json")

speeches <- content(json) %>%
  bind_rows()
```